# Using auth to know that a user is logged in

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase

My problem is this:

I have an entire site that was build with react and I connect to the site through the Nodejs, all the information of the site I basically take from the server side.

For the chat it is not possible to use a server side, because you need something called listeners, for the listeners you need to configure the firebase also in React and the listeners will work, for the chat you need to allow connected users to send messages, which will not be open to everyone. To know who is connected you need to use an option called auth.

I need the auth, for the rules in firebase I will only be able to allow connected users to access chat, and not leave the rules open to everyone.

*Chat works when I set rules in firebase to true, but I want only registered users to be able to use chat, I made it rules.*
[image]

*I'm getting an error of:*

```
Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

The problem is that I already connect via the server side, but need to somehow connect through the react as well, I also need to connect via react to see who is connected, and only for those who are connected I want to allow chat to be used. Need to connect via react, because only through react I manage to get all the functionality that firebase has to offer. The auth can only be obtained if you connect to firebase directly through react, but it requires that in react I will also connect for the chat. (Need listeners, because this way a user can immediately receive a message sent to him by someone, and need auth to allow only registered users access to chat)

To do that I need to connect via react, and use something called auth, to see who is connected. But the whole site itself is built around logging in through the nodejs, and in nodejs it is not possible to use auth. The nodejs can not keep track of auth, the nodejs only returns information in the end in JSON.

I do not know how to enable in react the connection with the auth, because of what I said, transfer all the connection to react, will drag to fill changes on the site, but login through the nodejs does not allow the use of auth, because it is a server side, my server side returns only JSON data and not functionality Beyond that like auth.

I was thinking of doing login times, both through the react and through nodejs, but then I'm afraid it will not work, because it might create 2 different tokens and only allow one of them to work.

I have tried to do other solutions like privateRoute, but still it does not help because one has to somehow get the auth, which allows to know who is connected. I would love if someone could help me if this or offer me a solution, I think there should be something that can be done with it and solve the problem.

How do I tell a firebase that a registered user wants to access chat?

Code of what I have done so far:

**Login via nodejs**

```
app.post('/login', login);


exports.login = (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  };

  const { valid, errors } = validateLoginData(user);

  if (!valid) return res.status(400).json(errors);

  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      return data.user.getIdToken();
    })
    .then((token) => {
      db.collection('users')
        .where("email", "==", user.email)
        .get()
        .then((data) => {
          data.forEach((doc) => {
            let userHandle = doc.data().handle;
            db.collection("users")
              .doc(userHandle)
              .get()
              .then((doc) => {
                let user = doc.data();
                db.collection('users').doc(userHandle)
                  .set(user)
                  .then(() => {
                    return res.json({ token: token});
                  })
                  .catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                    return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
                  });

              }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
              });


          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return res
        .status(403)
        .json({ general: "Wrong credentials, please try again" });
    });
};
```

**Using the nodejs login function**

```
export const loginUser = (userData, history) => (dispatch) => {
//userData contains mail and password  
axios
    .post('/login', userData)
    .then((res) => {
      setAuthorizationHeader(res.data.token);
      //maybe add the auth here somehow
      dispatch(getUserData());
      dispatch
        ({
          type: LOGIN_USER,
          payload: res.data.handle
        });

      history.push('/');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      });
    });
};
```

**PrivateRoute in react**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
  return(
    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => {
        const user = localStorage.getItem('user') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) : null;

        if(user){
            return <Component {...props} />
        }else{
            return <Redirect to={`/login`} />
        }

    }} />
   )

 }

export default PrivateRoute
```

**The authentication in react to connect**, but not chat, chat I'm not sure how to do

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import createMuiTheme from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import { SET_AUTHENTICATED } from './redux/types';
import { logoutUser, getUserData } from './redux/actions/userActions';
// Components
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import themeObject from './util/theme';
import AuthRoute from './util/AuthRoute';
import PrivateRoute from './util/PrivateRoute';

// Pages
import home from './pages/home';
import login from './pages/login';
import signup from './pages/signup';
import chat from './pages/chat';

import axios from 'axios';

const theme = createMuiTheme(themeObject);
axios.defaults.baseURL =
  'https://europe-west1-projectdemourl-b123c.cloudfunctions.net/api';

const token = localStorage.FBIdToken;
if (token) {
  const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
  if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    window.location.href = '/login';
  } else {
    store.dispatch({ type: SET_AUTHENTICATED });
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
    store.dispatch(getUserData());
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="container">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
                <AuthRoute exact path="/login" component={login} />
                <AuthRoute exact path="/signup" component={signup} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/chat" exact component={chat} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router>
        </Provider>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Login to firebase, client side**

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default firebase;
```

**The functions I use for chat**,
in these functions I use firebase

```
export const getRealtimeUsers = (handle) => {

    return async (dispatch) => {
        const db = firebase.firestore();
        const unsubscribe = db.collection("users")
            .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                db.collection('friends')
                    .get()
                    .then((data) => {
                        let friends = [];
                        data.forEach((doc) => {
                            if (doc.data().isFriends) {
                                if (doc.data().userHandleReceive == handle) {
                                    friends.push(doc.data().userHandleSend);
                                }
                                else {
                                    friends.push(doc.data().userHandleReceive);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        const users = [];
                        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                            if (doc.data().handle != handle && (friends.indexOf(doc.data().handle) > -1) ) {
                                users.push(doc.data());
                            }
                        });
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.error(err);
                    });
            });
        return unsubscribe;
    }
}

export const updateMessage = (msgObj) => {

    return async dispatch => {

        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection('conversations')
            .add({
                ...msgObj,
                isView: false,
                createdAt: new Date()
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });

    }
}



export const getRealtimeConversations = (user) => {
    return async dispatch => {

        const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection('conversations')
            .where('user_uid_1', 'in', [user.uid_1, user.uid_2])
            .orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')
            .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {

                const conversations = [];

                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    if (
                        (doc.data().user_uid_1 == user.uid_1 && doc.data().user_uid_2 == user.uid_2)
                        ||
                        (doc.data().user_uid_1 == user.uid_2 && doc.data().user_uid_2 == user.uid_1)
                    ) {
                        conversations.push(doc.data())
                    }

                });

                dispatch({
                    type: userConstants.GET_REALTIME_MESSAGES,
                    payload: { conversations }
                })
            })
    }
}
```

This is the main part of the code, another note I need to add the *loginUser function in react* option to auth

***I want to clarify, I create a user authenticated via Nodejs, but React not see it authenticated.***

***I'm just missing something here, the problem is very very small, but I can not figure out where it is, and how to fix it***

Comment: you may want to consider `console.log(req.body)` and your body-parser. You sure your req.body is not empty?

Comment: 2ndly if you want to use authentication with firestore/RTDB, you need the user to authenticate on the client side. EITHER - allow user login with email/password client side. OR - if you want to nodejs to authenticate, then you need to pass the JWT token to client side and allow client side to login with JWT, THEN you can see the auth info in firestore or RTDB

Comment: since you are using firebase, login in on react side or nodejs side is basically the same. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui infact most of us use client side login, not nodejs login.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Thanks for the comment, I did not understand what you mean, can you explain to me please what is "JWT" and how and where should I add it?

Comment: If you login via your custom nodejs, then you will need to maintain an identifier between your client and your server either through cookie, session or tokens etc. JWT is one of them, which is used with firebase. please refer to doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Thank you, I'm already using firebase's token, is it the same? How with the token I can actually solve this problem, it's just not clear to me

Comment: You only showed code from your node side, I'm not sure how you authenticate on client side.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial You're right, thanks for the comment, I just added the authentication process, but it's not working on chat right now

Comment: well u added the codes, but u did not show how you connect to database on client side... firebase rules works from the client side.

Comment: Thanks again, I did not quite understand what you mean, but I added up to 2 code snippets, one code showing my connection to firebase, and another code showing the functionality of the chat.

Please I would be happy if you could help me

Comment: Okay, I guess your problem *maybe* because you are using the database before your login is confirmed. The important part of firebase auth is probably onAuthStateChanged. You should only connect Firestore when onAuthStateChanged returns currentUser. You can refer to - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users . Your codes are all in pieces so I cannot help you. You have to help yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the problem, but I can not figure out how to do the. I would love if you could tell me where I should add it, I did not understand where to add it

Comment: try, then update the codes then we correct it.

Comment: I'm trying to fix the problem, but I can not figure out where it is, I can connect with the user, but probably the chat app does not see it, I would be happy if you could help me or offer me an idea.
I tried to do what you suggested to me, but I can not figure out where to put it

Comment: You have to implement cookieless JWT,  and pass an authoization bearer in the header. This will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several flaws in your reasoning and several mistakes in your code.

### Fundamentally:
Why login both at the server side and the client side?

If you want your users to login to your database to read and/or write, you can do so on the client side or you can do it on the server side. Both offer almost the same options.

Doing it on both the server and the client doesn't make much sense. Begs the question: why you want to do both?...

#### Solution:

Since you are collecting the user's login info in your html page, why not just login the user immediately on the client side too?

Take this simple HTML, which has two inputs and loads three firebase scripts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input name="email" id="email" type="text">
    <input name="password" id="password" type="text">
    <button type="button" id="login">Login</button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Add the `ìndex.js` file next to it in the same folder:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAg2{.....}z7ObRoXg-goy9jc",
    authDomain: "s{.....}3.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "st{.....}40f63",
    storageBucket: "stacksh{.....}pspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "537{.....}09",
    appId: "1:537{.....}04409:web:2{.....}7a6b67c14fa48"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var db = firebase.firestore();
/* We listen for button click and then log in the user */
var button = document.getElementById('login');
button.addEventListener('click',function(){
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            alert("logged in");
            getRealtimeUsers();
            
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
            return err;
        });
    
});
function getRealtimeUsers(){
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    });
}
```

If you also need to login on the server side, for whatever reason, you can do so using your server-side login.

Caution
Your server-side code contains a major flaw. It should wait for the promise to resolve:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const config =  {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAg2GWsL04akpMNezuuz7ObRoXg-goy9jc",
    authDomain: "stackshop-40f63.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "stackshop-40f63",
    storageBucket: "stackshop-40f63.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "537745304409",
    appId: "1:537745304409:web:2a8bb1f007a6b67c14fa48"
};

const firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Log user in
async function login(req, res)  { 
    const user = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    };
    await firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then((data) => {
            
            firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(false).then(function(idToken) {
                      // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
                      // ...
                    res.send(idToken);
                    //signInWithCustomToken()
                    
                }).catch(function(error) {
                  // Handle error
                });
            return data;
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
            return err;
        });
}
app.post('/login', login);
```